# Vertical line in Histogram with Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, line, histogram, mean

Can someone please tell me if it is possible to draw a vertical line to indicate the mean value of the data in a histogram using excel or google sheet?

I found ways to do it with python and R, but I need to find a way to do in excel.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Draw Vertical Line to Histogram Graph on Google Charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981689/how-draw-vertical-line-to-histogram-graph-on-google-charts)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I need to get it done in Excel to prepare a template for other histograms too.